# applying ::selection css to a div

Tags: html, css

When you apply a class with a particular color for the ::selection pseudoclass to a div, it only seems to effect the spans inside that div but not the rest of the text why is that? and is there a way to apply a custom selection color to a div. See the JSFiddle for an example of attaching a class with a ::selection color to both a div (which does not work as I would expect) and the body which does work as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/m9ZxB/3/

relevant css:

```
.green ::selection{
  background:green;   
}
```

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2008Oct/0268.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35146) on bugzilla which relates to your problem.

As you can see in [comment 26](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35146#c26) a selection is actually an extra anonymous element, that's why text-decoration of the surrounding anchor won't change its color since the selector only applies for this "child": `<span>The word <span::selection>select</span::selection> is selected</span>`.

and please also note

> Though this pseudo-element was in drafts of CSS Selectors Level 3, it
>   was removed during the Candidate Recommendation phase,  as it appeared
>   that its behavior was under-specified, especially with nested
>   elements, and interoperability wasn't achieved (based on discussion in
>   the W3C Style mailing list).

Visit this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection) post for more information